# How to split a long entered in TextBox control into int array

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing, split

I just started to learn C# and already have a question, maybe quite dumb.

I'm writing a little desktop program (Windows Forms) that checks whether entered bank account number is valid or computes missing control numbers. To check number validity we must multiply each digit in that number by corresponding factor. My problem is:

When I enter whole number (26 digits) in TextBlock control and click Check button I need to parse that number into int array somehow. I saw some examples already and tried

```
int[] array = new int[26];
char[] sep = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

String[] numbers = inputWindow.Text.Split(sep);

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    array[i] = Int32.Parse(numbers[i]);
```

But got FormatException. I also tried

```
array = inputWindow.Text.Split().Select(h => Int32.Parse(h)).ToArray());
```

Or something similar but got OverflowException. Int64.Parse resulted in obvious type conversion error. How to accomplish that parsing?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
My bad, there was 30 instead of 26, but that actually didn't matter.

Comment: Do you have an example of the input, and expected output?

Comment: `string.Split` removes the separators, so that first example will never return any numeric digits.  The default delimiters for `string.Split` are white-space characters, so that second example will not split the digits unless they have spaces between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That second snippet is almost there (assuming you want an array of numbers, and that the `Text` property has *only* numbers in it).

Remove the call to `Split()`, and the `Select()` portion will iterate over each character in the string.

```
var array = inputWindow.Text.Select(i => Convert.ToInt32(i-48)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Let's say I've got this bank account number 88124045331111001018545411 and I need to check whether it is valid. This number contains 26 digits and each of them has to be multiplied by corresponding factor (different for each digit). I need to split this number into int array, then do the whole computing and the result must be of course information: "Valid"

Comment: @Colonder If you need help with the algorithm to validate the array of digits, then you should ask a new question.

Comment: No, I don't need help with that I just needed advice on parsing. Grant Winney done the thing, thanks

Comment: Actually `Convert.ToInt32` when used on a `char` will give the Ascii value, not the equivalent digit value, so `Convert.ToInt32('1')` will give you 49, not 1.  You need to `ToString` the `char` and it will work, or just do `.Select(c => c - 48)`.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this in a console application and I was able to get the numbers into the array.  I did no math on each one.  I assume you could take it from there.  I also recommend using a List instead of an array so the size is not fixed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Number: ");
        string inputStr = Console.ReadLine();
        int[] array = new int[30];

        int i = 0;
        foreach(Char c in inputStr)
        {
            array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString());
            i++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");

        foreach (int num in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your whole number just 26 digits,but your i set max is 30 `for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)`, 26 is less than 30,so `array[i] = Int32.Parse(numbers[i])` throw OverflowException

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet can be used to convert TextBox text to integer array. But you have to make sure that user will input only interger in textBox.

```
  int[] array = new int[30];
        char[] sample = textBox1.Text.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            array[i] = int.Parse(sample[i].ToString());
```